# How to create join table records in has_and_belongs_to_many rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Students can have many teachers and teachers can have many students.

This association works fine defined here:

```
#teacher.rb

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end


#student.rb

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
  validates :email, format: /\A[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}\z/
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 3 }

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def age
    today = Date.today
    years_passed = today.years_ago(birthday.year).year
    today.month < birthday.month ? years_passed -= 1 : years_passed
  end

  def self.distribute_students
    count = 0

    Student.all.each do |student|
      # TODO: Count
      count += 1
      count = 0 if count >= Teacher.count + 1
    end
  end
end
```

How can I use my distribute_students method, what it should do is

for each student add a row in students_teachers where `student_id = currentstudentid`
and `teacher_id=count`

`count` being the variable in `distribute_each`

Comment: I suspect you want add not a column, but a row? And I don't clearly understand the meaning of teacher_id = count. Do you want to evenly distribute you students among teachers? So as a result each student will have only one teacher

Comment: Yes they would still only have one teacher. How can I insert a row into teacher_students? Since some students don't have teachers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a somewhat random distribution from `Teacher` to `Student`, but you should be simply able to do it by finding your `Teacher` object and assigning it to the `teachers` as in

```
my_teacher = Teacher.find(count)
student.teachers << my_Teacher
```

which of course assumes that all your `Teacher`s are numbered consecutively (which `Rails` does not guarantee and there are bound to be teachers who quit soon given this method of `Student` distribution :-). A better solution would be to fetch all teachers before the loop and to work with an array. That would save you from going through one more database call in every loop. That would make it something like

```
all_teachers = Teacher.all
Student.all.each do |student|
  count += 1
  count = 0 if count >= all_teachers.count
  student.teachers << all_teachers[count]
end
```